# Trying to swipe pages in PVC in container view by segmented control, Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am looking for help in my xamarin.ios app.

What is my goal:
[image]

I am working on a screen, where I have to use container view, in which should be page view controller - in this PVC I put pages into by code:

```
public partial class PageViewController : UIPageViewController
{
    private List<UIViewController> pages = new List<UIViewController>();
    //private UISegmentedControl control;
    public PageViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    { 
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        UIViewController p1 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("id1");
        UIViewController p2 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("id2");
        pages.Add(p1);
        pages.Add(p2);
        this.DataSource = new PageDataSource(pages);

        SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { pages[0], pages[1] }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, null);
    }
}
```

(I add only 2 pages, because the 3rd page will be similar to 2nd page)

But there is still the View Controller, where is my Segmented Control, and I want to use the SC to switch the pages.
This is also the PageDataSource class:

```
public class PageDataSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    private List<UIViewController> pages;
    //private UISegmentedControl control;

    public PageDataSource(List<UIViewController> p)
    {
        pages = p;
        //control = c;
    }

    public override UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var index = pages.IndexOf(referenceViewController);
        if (index < pages.Count - 1)
        {
            index++;
            //control.SelectedSegment = index;
            return pages[index];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var index = pages.IndexOf(referenceViewController);

        if(index == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            index = index - 1;
            //control.SelectedSegment = index;
            return pages[index];
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any tips, any experience with IOS apps created in Xamarin, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the following code whether can get the view controller from storyboard:

```
 UIViewController p1 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("id1");
 UIViewController p2 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("id2");
```

Have a try with this way to get the view controller:

```
UIViewController p1 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("P1ViewController") as P1ViewController;
UIViewController p2 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("P2ViewController") as P2ViewController;
```

If you want to add a `UISegmentedControl`, you could have a look at following code(The sample not getting Child ViewController from StoryBoard):

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    private List<UIViewController> pages = new List<UIViewController>();
    UIPageViewController pvController;

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {


    }

    private void SegmentedControl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sg = sender as UISegmentedControl;
        if (sg.SelectedSegment == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0");
            pvController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { pages[0] }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, s => { });
        }
        else if (sg.SelectedSegment == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            pvController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { pages[1] }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, s => { });
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        this.PresentModalViewController(pvController, true);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        UIViewController p1 = new UIViewController();
        p1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        p1.Title = "First controller";
        UIViewController p2 = new UIViewController();
        p2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
        p2.Title = "Second controller";
        pages.Add(p1);
        pages.Add(p2);
        //Create the UIPageViewController and it's basic style
        pvController = new UIPageViewController(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal);
        //Specify the data source for the pages
        pvController.DataSource = new PageDataSource(pages);
        pvController.View.Frame = View.Bounds;
        //Set the initial content (first pages)
        pvController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { pages[0] }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, s => { });
        //...etc...

        UISegmentedControl segmentedControl = new UISegmentedControl();
        segmentedControl.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 200, 30);
        segmentedControl.InsertSegment("One", 0, true);
        segmentedControl.InsertSegment("Two", 1, true);
        segmentedControl.ValueChanged += SegmentedControl_ValueChanged;
        pvController.View.AddSubview(segmentedControl);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

**Note**: You need to use `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll` when using `UISegmentedControl`, because it can switch them to show one by one.

The effect:

[image]
[image]